# Get mobile number using react-native-facebook-account-kit

Tags: react-native, account-kit

Currently im using [react-native-facebook-account-kit](https://github.com/underscopeio/react-native-facebook-account-kit) to verify phone number for my native app. In this plugin there is a method called loginWithPhone() which is generating input and verification UI. So i dont have any control over that fields where users are typing their mobile number. How can i get the mobile number after the user typed it or after verification?

Comment: Bro did you find any solution for this..??

Comment: @AFLAHALI no bro.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in RNAccountKit.configure(), change responseType to 'code'

Comment: Thank you for your time, Its been too long that i was working on that project. I will let you know if it is working or not :)

Comment: Not working for me how i can get mobile number that has been entered in account kit

Answer (score 0):

> This work for me!

```
RNAccountKit.loginWithPhone()
.then((code) => {
    if (!code) {
      console.log('Login cancelled')
    } else {
      this._showMessage("Logged with phone. Token: "+JSON.stringify(code) );

 RNAccountKit.getCurrentAccount()
 .then((account) => {
 console.log("Current account:"+ JSON.stringify(account))
 })
}
 });
```